# Change wrong french characters on table

Tags: sql-server

For some reason we found on the database characters like this: Ã
I can assume this character represent the character: é

Now I need to revise the whole table but checking all other characters to make sure there are no others.

Where I can find the relation of characters for example between this Ã and é? or probably find an SQL function that is already done to make those replacement.

I'm using SQL Server 2014

Comment: `'Ã'` and `'é'` *are* different characters from SQL Server's perspective; there is no "relationship" between the two. Likely these have been entered incorrectly by a user or ,somewhere in your application, you're using 2 different text encodes and the character is getting "changed" as a result.

Comment: ok thank you, so you says there is no relation between both? so literaly I need to scan all possible issues and validate which one is the corresponding one?

Comment: Not sure what you really mean there I'm afraid, sorry.

Comment: Seems to be an **encoding** problem. Can you show us some data ? Because "é" can be display "Ã©" when ithere is a confusion between  UTF-8 / ISO 8859-1

Comment: That's what I want, where can I find that "é" can be displayed like "Ã©" and other characters?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Daniel E, your dirty data might have been caused by the use of incorrect code pages (UTF-8 that was interpreted as ISO 8859-1).

One way to find entries with dirty data, is to use a "not exists" ("^") like expression with the list of valid characters in that expression. See example below.

```
declare @t table (name varchar(20))
insert into @t values ('touchÃ©')
insert into @t values ('encore touché')
insert into @t values ('reçu')
insert into @t values ('hello world')

select * from @t where name like '%[^a-zA-Z., -]%'

select * from @t where name like '%[^a-zA-Z.,èêé -]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

Comment: Note that SQL Server 2014 does use UTF-8 to encode text but UTF-16.

Comment: é (E WITH ACUTE, LATIN SMALL LETTER Unicode 00e9) is encode to 00e9 in UTF-16 but c3a9 in UTF-8. If you decode c3a9 using 8859-1 you get Ã©.